# NSIS: prompt the user to choose his/her own installation files/directory

Tags: c#, installation, nsis

I can't for my life figure this out and I've been googling for ages.

Instead of having defined files to be installed in the .nsi file, how do I promp the user to choose a directory he/she wants to install himself? The type of a directory/files shouldn't be my problem. My only concern is the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to build your own dialog using the [nsDialog](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html) plug-in. Have a look at `nsDialogs::SelectFileDialog` and `nsDialogs::SelectFolderDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you ask is possible.

If you can place the files to be installed in a specific folder you can use
`File /r ToInstall`.

For copying our manual I'm using this, the base install is always the same,  but the manuals will vary based on customer (and are not my problem)

```
Section Manuals
IfFileExists $EXEDIR\Manuals\*.* InstallManual NoManual

InstallManual:
    CreateDirectory $INSTDIR\Manuals
    CopyFiles /Silent $EXEDIR\Manuals\*.* $INSTDIR\Manuals

NoManual:
SectionEnd
```

Otherwise prompt from the shell and store the location in an environment variable?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express myself clearly. I want the user to BE ASKED to BROWSE and choose the Installation file he/she wants to install. The file which is normally defined in the NSIS script by the following code: "File C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"(this file is just an example of course). The user should be able to choose either one file or the whole directory.